# Fetch value from string expression like "Add Watch" feature

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public class UFMLine
{
    public UFMTemplate elementTag;
    public int posX1;
    public int posY1;
    public int posX2;
    public int posY2;
    public string property;
    public string hierStr = string.Empty;
    public List<UFMLine> ufmLines = new List<UFMLine>(); // the tricky nested class field
}

UFMLine ufmobj = new UFMLine();
```

This ufmobj is populated perfectly at the window load.

In my button click of wpf window xaml code behind...

```
string nthItem =  "ufmobj.ufmLines[0].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[2].ufmLines[2].elementTag";

 // Tried reflection method, but giving null exception
 var result = typeof(UFMLine).GetField(nthItem).GetValue(ufmobj);
```

So when opening watch window and fetch the value for nthItem name it gives appropriate value.

How to get it in the code behind or am i not properly using the reflection?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. You don't just want to get the appropriate UFMLine object? What is your expected `var result`?

Comment: my mistake, edited it.

Comment: Still not clear. Which type do you expect `result` to be?

Comment: //Which type do you expect result to be?
Its UFMTemplate enum variable.

Comment: Then it should just be `var result = ufmobj.ufmLines[0]. ... .elementTag;`

Comment: Pardon me Clemens, I have now included properly as doublequotes in the string nthItem = "ufmobj.ufmLines[0]. ... .elementTag";

Comment: That won't work, and what would be the sense? I really don't get it. Please add significantly more details to your question (not as comment). Write a clear and understandable description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you storing code in a string in the first place? Either way, `GetField` only gives you field information, it doesn't operate on actual instances or values (nor does it parse and evaluate code at run-time). You'll have to manually parse that string before you can use reflection to do what you want.

Comment: Prepared the string nthItem by using the value stored in the the database received in json as "0/1/1/1/2/2" - This denotes Parent - Child relationship in a hierarchical manner. The last number "2" denotes that his parent is "2" and the parent's parent is 1 and so on reaching the grandest parent "0". ufmobj object is prepared by parsing an another json.

Comment: If you change the fields of your class to public properties, you could simply use a WPF Binding with your nthItem string as `Path`.

Comment: It looks like you don't need any reflection at all. Just extract those indices from that string and write a simple for loop: `var current = ufmobj; foreach (var index in indices) { current = current.ufmLines[index]; } var result = current.elementTag;`

Comment: @clemens, This seems very new. I will try the WPF Binding and it would be very helpful if you can provide a url.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet did you mean calling the looping method in recursive?

Comment: That loop is sufficient, no need for recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the fields of your `UFMLine` class to public properties:

```
public class UFMLine
{
    public UFMTemplate elementTag { get; set; }
    public int posX1 { get; set; }
    public int posY1 { get; set; }
    public int posX2 { get; set; }
    public int posY2 { get; set; }
    public string property { get; set; }
    public string hierStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<UFMLine> ufmLines { get; set; } = new List<UFMLine>();
}
```

Now you could use the part of your `nthItem` string after `"ufmobj."` as the Path of a Binding, for which you would use `ufmobj` as Source:

```
var binding = new Binding
{
    Source = ufmobj,
    Path = new PropertyPath("ufmLines[0].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[1].ufmLines[2].ufmLines[2].elementTag")
};
```

To make use of this Binding, you would also need a target dependency property, which you might declare in a helper class like this:

```
public class BindingHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Result", typeof(object), typeof(MainWindow));

    public object Result
    {
        get { return GetValue(ResultProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResultProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Finally you would assign the Binding to the Target property and then retrieve the resulting value like this:

```
var bindingHelper = new BindingHelper();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(bindingHelper, BindingHelper.ResultProperty, binding);
var result = bindingHelper.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks @clemens for not using loops. This worked like a charm and It was a great help to overcome my stagnated situation.

Answer (score 1):

The "name" of the variable (`ufmobj`) could be a problem since it could be lost in a release build, but the rest can be achieved with reflection if you don't mind implementing your own parser.

1. Split path (Syntax of your choice)
2. Resolve one path segment after another
3. Determine if path is Field/Property/Indexer/Method/etc.
4. Repeat until done

Here is a small snippet to get you going (far from complete, but works with your example):

Resolve a single Field or Property

```
private object GetFieldOrProperty(object obj, string name)
{
    Type objType = obj.GetType();

    if (objType.GetField(name) != null)
        return objType.GetField(name).GetValue(obj);
    if (objType.GetProperty(name) != null)
        return objType.GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
    return null;
}
```

Resolve the entire path:

```
private object Resolve(object parent, string path)
{
    string[] paths = path.Split('.');

    foreach (string p in paths)
    {
        if (p.EndsWith("]"))
        {
            int start = p.IndexOf("[");
            string property = p.Substring(0, start);
            string index = p.Substring(start + 1, p.Length - start - 2);

            parent = GetFieldOrProperty(parent, property);
            if (parent == null)
                return null;

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (info.GetIndexParameters().Length < 1) continue;

                parent = info.GetValue(parent, new object[] {int.Parse(index)});
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            parent = GetFieldOrProperty(parent, p);
            if (parent == null)
                return null;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Test case:

```
UFMLine ufmobj = new UFMLine();
ufmobj.ufmLines.Add(new UFMLine());
ufmobj.ufmLines[0].ufmLines.Add(new UFMLine());
ufmobj.ufmLines[0].ufmLines[0].ufmLines.Add(new UFMLine{property = "Success"});
Debug.WriteLine(Resolve("ufmLines[0].ufmLines[0].ufmLines[0].property.Length", ufmobj));
```

> 7 (length of "Success")

Comment: Thanks Manfred, I will check it out and hit back at the earliest.

Comment: This works and as you said, it is an own parsing method with nested foreach. Implemented WPF binding suggested by @clemens. Thanks manfred.